# Pass javascript variable to php - Google+ API

Tags: javascript, php

Google+ API allows getting the number of comments from an URL using the following code:

```
<div id="commentscounter"></div>
<script>
gapi.commentcount.render('commentscounter', {
    href: window.location
});
</script>
```

I have red, that you can pass the value of a javascript variable to php using something like this:

```
<?php
echo "Comments: ".$_GET['commentscounter']."<br>";
?>
```

Of course, that would do the job if the variable commentscounter was defined in the previous javascript, but this is not the case here. It looks like, that the javascript just renders the number of comments, but do not define it.

Do you have an idea of how can I obtain the value itself? I need it because the API renders it in following format (8 comments). I want to explode the result and keep just the number to use in some calculations.

Comment: You'll need AJAX to pass it back to the server.

Comment: I suggest you to read their API documentation based on json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event of jQuery, [pass the inner html value](https://api.jquery.com/html/) of the div with id 'commentscounter' through [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your php script.